# Qt example audio recorder cannot save as wav file

Tags: qt, qt5, audio-recording, qtmultimedia

I compiled Qt multimedia exaple `audio recorder`. But there's no `wav` option under `File container`. Are there some packages or libs that I didn't install?

Qt version: 5.8.0

OS: Archlinux 4.11.2